# Does sleep/nanosleep cause a process to give up the remainder of its time slice immediately?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, scheduling

I'm wondering does `sleep()`/`nanosleep()` cause a process to give up the remainder of its time slice immediately? And can other threads or processes utilize the rest of the time slice directly?

I wrote a program called `nanosleep()` to sleep *n* nanoseconds repeatedly. Can I use this program to prove the system calls indeed cause the process to give up its rest of time slice immediately **if the times of nanosleep() called is as many as the count of context switch occurred**?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
   struct timespec tim, tim2;
   tim.tv_sec = t.tv_sec;
   tim.tv_nsec = 1000000; // n nanoseconds

   int ret;
   while (1) {
       ret = nanosleep(&tim, &tim2);
       if (ret < 0) {
           perror("nano sleep");
       }
   }
}
```

*n* is much less than a time slice.

e.g. when the n = 1000000(= 1ms = 1/1000s), the `cs` column value from `vmstat 1` command is 1400~1600
,and when the n = 2000000(= 2ms), the cs column value is 800~900

Comment: [nanosleep manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html): *nanosleep() suspends the execution of the calling thread*. So the short answer is - yes.

Comment: Any *sleep or system resource requests, or any other synch primitive, on any multitask OS, yields the execution. It is the base of tasks synchronization. The remaining of time slice isn't a remaining, because the execution slots normally aren't fixed, so the new execution thread will start just subsequently, and will last for the associated execution time, unless it also yelds eecution.

Comment: Neither `sleep()` nor `nanosleep()` are synchronization functions.  If you are relying on them for ordering events, you are almost certainly doing something wrong.  So whether or not they cause a process to "give up the remainder of its time slice" is fundamentally not really all that important except in extremely particular circumstances.

Comment: That is the *point* of `sleep()` - to relinquish the time slice and not hog the processor by doing nothing, and wasting resources.

Comment: 'give up the remainder of its time slice' ..... ugh...